# Load WPF Style with negative Value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following Stlye

```
<Style x:Key="xPad" TargetType="TextBlock">
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,3,-6,3"/>
</Style>
```

If I use this style in XAML it works as expected.
But when I try to load this in code:

```
        object o = Application.Current.TryFindResource("xPad");
```

I get an argument exception that the value 2,3,-6,3 is not a valid value for System.Windows.Documents.Block.Padding.

Comment: Read the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.padding(v=vs.110).aspx and use `Margin` instead.

Comment: My Problem (I guess) is that it loads a ...Documents.Block.Padding... whil it should be a ...Controls.Padding

And I can't use margin since I have to change a complex (partially dynamic) layout from a third party component

It works from XAML but I have to do it from code for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be your `Padding` values results in the negative height and width while calculating size and you are probably getting the exception *Height and width must be non-negative* in your inner-exceptions

[image: Padding]

From this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300505/wpf-width-and-height-must-be-non-negative) answer: 
It turns out if your window is larger than your screen, you'll probably get negative values, for either position or size.

So, I'm guessing your padding values `2,3,-6,3` (left,top,right,bottom) might be resulting the windows larger than the screen size. Because it throws the exception while calling `get_size` and as I tested, if you simply change your values to `2,3,-2,3', it would work.

Comment: I don't even assign it - I just try to load - it works from XAML - and it works from code with positive values